# Instagram secure API requests

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Instagram will enforce [signed requests](https://instagram.com/developer/secure-api-requests/) for all API requests starting [September 1st](http://developers.instagram.com/post/116410697261/publishing-guidelines-and-signed-requests).

Unit tests are easy. And for integration tests Instagram suggests to make a cURL call.

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -F 'access_token=<your_access_token>' \
  -F 'sig=<your_signature>' \
  https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/657988443280050001_25025320/likes
```

The thing is that our app does not request `likes` scope, so the response from that call is not we expect.

```
HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST

{"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthPermissionsException","code":400,"error_message":"This request requires scope=likes, but this access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your application with scope=likes to be granted write permissions."}}
```

With `GET` calls `sig` is silently ignored by the API. Is there a way to test our signature code before September 1st using `basic` scope only?